# KOMAscript - title page: Title font does not increase in size

Tags: koma-script

I try to get a title page done and have filled the respective fields. I have used `addtokomafont` to adapt the size of the text lines. Title and Author both have the size `Huge` but the title line font is smaller than the author line (by about 50%). What is wrong? Would there be a simple way to use just for the title (not for the other title matter) a formated text? (I have KOMA script v. 3.21)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=156mm:234mm, BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
%   footsepline=true,   mach strich, nicht abstand
    headsepline=true,
    headings=normal,
    }

% % titel
\addtokomafont{subject}{\raggedright\LARGE\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{title}{\Huge\raggedright\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{subtitle}{\raggedright\LARGE\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{author}{\Huge\raggedright\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}}
\addtokomafont{publishers}{\LARGE\raggedright}

%\titlehead{{\Large TitleHead \\}
%   moretitlehead}
\subject{Contesting Ontology \\}
\title{The forms   Buildings and Real Estate or Buildings and Real Estate\\ \vspace{1cm}}
\subtitle{Writings on something or other\\ \vspace{5mm}1999 - 2999}
\author{\vspace{2cm}Andrew U. Frank}
\date{}
\publishers{\vfill topdown Editions\\Vol. xz}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is a duplicate - I could not find the mentioned question...